# HTML5 Validation Not Trigering

Tags: html, validation, validity.js

I'm working on making client side validation for inputs.
I had had been using PHP to do it all.
Needless to say things got cluttered very quickly.
So I looked in to JS and HTML5 and want to move in to that system for validation.

The messages I want to show are like this:

[image: Email Popup Message]

I know that these are done with the the `<input type="email">` tag.

After some help, I was pointed to this page [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/).

However I cant seem to get anything to popup.
I copied code straight from there site and nothing.

```
<input id="foo" type="number" max="2" value="1" />
<input id="bar" type="number" max="2" value="3" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById('foo').validity.rangeOverflow; //false
        document.getElementById('bar').validity.rangeOverflow; //true
    </script>
```

What am I missing to make the notification appear?

Comment: What do you mean by HTML field? Do you mean JavaScript, not Java?

Comment: Try JqueryUI ToolTip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: The technique you are illustrating is **tooltips.** There are several techniques that combine validation with tooltips; try [looking for those](https://www.google.com/search?q=tooltips%20html%20validation).

Comment: Actually, in HTML5 he can simply use the email field which the browser validates.

Comment: *Show an effort*: provide any attempt to solve this problem. Usually, this means providing your idea to solve the problem and, in most cases, the code to solve the problem.

Comment: @maythesource.com: It appears that HTML validation offers a less specific error message.

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦ The error message he gets is the exact pop-up chrome provides for e-mail validation. Press submit on: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_email . You will see this is the case.

Comment: @maythesource.com: Ah.  Fitting for an answer.

Comment: They are native form validation tooltips: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: `<input type="email" />` - why won't more people use this? :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey - You can actually define your own messages with `.setCustomValidity` but in this case it is the default text in Chrome.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am using that, I'm wanting to make the came alert come up with other inputs. Derek has given me the answer that needed.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 If you will type up an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @WhiteShadow - You can accept Jere's answer instead since this question is closed and I couldn't add a new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That popup is a new implementation in HTML5. Just create an input field like this:

```
<input type="email">
```

The popup appears automatically when the form is submitted if the input isn't an email-address.

More about the new input fields in HTML5 is at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

Comment: Look at my answer if you just need a simple run down of how I fixed **my** problem.

Answer (score 0):

Form must be submitted before validation kicks in.

So you have to add a button with the type of `submit` so like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="blah">
```

And then you have to enclose all the fields/inputs in a `<form>` and `</form>` tag.

here is the working code:

```
<form> 
    <input id="foo" type="number" max="2" value="1" />
    <input id="bar" type="number" max="2" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" value="blah">
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('foo').validity.rangeOverflow; //false
    document.getElementById('bar').validity.rangeOverflow; //true
</script>
```